# AIY Voice Kit with Voice HAT on Raspberry Pi 3 suddenly requires Google Assistant on phone. Why?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk, google-aiy

After deleting all activity associated with the Google account linked to the **AIY Voice Kit** Pi project, the Assistant no longer responds to voice input queries. Now the Assistant responds, *"Actually there are some basic settings that need your permission first. Just go into the Google Assistant settings on your phone for more details."* I did not use a phone for initial setup of the AIY Voice Kit project. Why would I need to use a phone now? Is there a workaround that I can do using the web interface of my Google account?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! On this site and Stack Exchange in general, it's considered good practice to accept an answer if it answers your question. From your comment below, it seems like your question was answered. Accepting helps everyone out- the person who answers gets a small reputation boost, that answer moves to the top, which helps out people who may have the same question, and the question is marked as answered, so people looking for unanswered questions aren't distracted by questions that don't need any more answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [follow these instructions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/config-dev-project-and-account#set-activity-controls) through the web to enable certain permissions in order to use the Assistant.

- Open the [Activity Controls page](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols)
- Ensure the following toggles are on:

  - Web & App Activity

    - In addition, be sure to select the Include Chrome browsing history and activity from websites and apps that use Google services checkbox.
  - Device Information
  - Voice & Audio Activity

Comment: Thank you. It was not straightforward because the Google account I had linked to the Google Assistant SDK was managed by a corporate admin. I had to request a change in an organizational level setting for the Chrome browsing history checkbox to be available to select.

Comment: Ah, it may be easier to use a personal Gmail account to do this credentials as you may not have the same restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a corporate managed Google account with the Google Assistant SDK ask your administrator to turn on Web & App Activity (for everyone or just your account). Ours was turned off for everyone which prevents an individual user from selecting the "Include Chrome browsing history and activity from websites and apps that use Google services" checkbox.

[Google Admin G-Suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knmVx.png)